# How do I repair a glass cooker hob (glass top stove)?

Tags: repair, stove-top, glass-top-range

We have a glass cooker hob (glass top stove) where the black glass has chipped at one edge. Is there a repair system that will hide the damage?

I am looking for something that is gloss block that will stick on the glass, so as to hide the chips.

This is what I mean by a "cooker hob"
[image]

Comment: Is this perhaps about a glass cook top for a kitchen stove? Or something else?

Comment: @woodchips: I would guess so. According to [cooking.SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/2291) a British 'hob' is an American range or stove.

Comment: Use an epoxy ...they sell them in all kinds of colors. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently is for a smooth glass top on a stove. GE sells them, perhaps others now. Traditionally, the word is that these are generally replaced when cracked. A small chip on the edge may not be worth replacing the top (which is EXPENSIVE from what I've heard) until that crack chooses to propagate. The problem is, heat stresses in glass tend to turn small cracks into big ones.

You might ask the manufacturer, but I'll bet a large sum of money they have no interest in repair anyway. They want to sell you a new top.

The first solution I would think of is a high temperature silicon caulk. You can buy it in a tube, and it does come in black. I don't know how much it hardens though.

If not that, I would look for a high temperature epoxy. You can get colorants for epoxy.

Comment: What is "caulk"? I have never seen it for sale in the UK

Comment: This stuff, if you can find it in black. I know that I have done so in the past. The problem is, it tends to stay flexible.   http://www.accentshopping.com/product.asp?P_ID=152285

Answer (score 1):

If it's only chipped, and not actually a crack forming, I'd think that you'd be able to just add a little bit of trim over the very edge.  The glass doesn't tend to get too hot over on the sides, but there'd be a good chance of taking a hot pan, and it coming into contact, so you'd want something that could take heat (so not most plastics).  It's possible that they'd sell it at home improvement type stores ... I hate that little gap between my stove and my counter, as something always falls in there and you have to go fish it out.

If it's started cracking, I'd actually think about getting one of those glue & vaccuum kits they use for repairing car windshields, where you use a vacuum to try to force the glue into the crack, let it cure, and then scrape off any surface residue.  I'm guessing they use CA glue (cyanoacrylate, aka "super glue"), but I don't know how thick -- the thicker ones have a longer cure time, but they won't penetrate as well due to capillary action.  You'd want to check to make sure that it's a CA mix that's rated for use on glass.  (pure CAs don't stick well to glass)